# How can i merge partitions by pairs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a set of points(each point is a line in a text file), which I spread between Spark's partitions.

I use the mapPartitions action which results me half of the points in each partition(doesn't really matter why and how).

Now, I want to merge the partition by pairs, so partition #1 and #2 will be a merged partition, partition #3 and #4 will be the second merged partition and so one.

I will continue to run mapPartitions until I left with a few partitions only.
How can I do that with Spark?

The analogs to Hadoop here is that i merge the output files by pairs and run the taks again.

I will try to clarify it again: I have x partitions, after I run mapPartitions,
I want to merge them by pairs so i would have x/2 partitions and run mapPartitions again and so on..

Comment: If you downvote it will great to know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`treeAggregate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L906) as a model something like this should do the trick:

```
from math import log

def binaryReduce(rdd, f):
    assert log(rdd.getNumPartitions(), 2) % 1 == 0
    def mapPartition(i, iter):
        i = i / 2
        for x in iter:
            yield i, x

    while rdd.getNumPartitions() != 1:
        rdd = (rdd
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex(mapPartition)
            .reduceByKey(f, rdd.getNumPartitions() / 2)
            .values())

    return rdd.first()
```

If you prefer more explicit approach you keep partition numbers all the way through:

```
def binaryReduce(rdd, f):
    assert log(rdd.getNumPartitions(), 2) % 1 == 0

    def initPartition(i, iter):
        for x in iter:
            yield i, x

    rdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(initPartition)

    while rdd.getNumPartitions() != 1:
        rdd = (rdd
            .reduceByKey(f)
            .map(lambda x: (x[0] / 2, x[1]))
            .partitionBy(rdd.getNumPartitions() / 2))

    return rdd.values().reduce(f)
```

For Python 3.0+ be sure to replace `/` with `//`.

Comment: how does values() effects on this?  Does it gather all partitions together?
Can it mix values between partitions?

Comment: It simply drops keys: [`def values(): JavaRDD[V] = JavaRDD.fromRDD[V](rdd.map(_._2))`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/69c9c177160e32a2fbc9b36ecc52156077fca6fc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.scala#L933)

Comment: so if it doesnt swap values between partitions, what is the difference between both approaches you showed me here?

Comment: Also, why r u using this assertion?

Comment: _Also, why r u using this assertion? _ - to be able to create a full binary tree. `what is the difference between both approaches you showed me here` - You can argue that the first one depends on the the details of implementation but otherwise there is no practical difference.

Comment: In the second approach, I change the number of partitions, how does it effect on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite obscure. 
If I get it right you could try a reduceByKey after mapping your data to (key,value).

(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: You should use mapPartitionsWithIndex(func) with func that must be of type (Int, Iterator) => Iterator.

Comment: great suggestion, but how can i number the partitions?
I want to have partition 1, 2,3... how can I achieve that?
I mean: I need to give the key in a way that it will be helpful to reduceByKey, how can i get it?

Comment: You just have to be sure that values from partitions you want to be joined together have the same key.

Comment: I want that first two partitions will have key 1, next two with key 2 and so on.
How can i know what key to give to each partition?Its very close to the solution im looking for

Comment: mapPartitionsWithIndex(func), 
func must be of type (Int, Iterator<T>) => Iterator<U>.
Use int/2 as key? since int is the partition number, you will have partition number 1 and 2 with key = 1, 3 and 4 with key = 2 and so on.

Comment: sounds cool. 
after i will reduceByKey, each key will be assigned to its partition?
I mean, i cant have key = 4 splitted between two different partitions?

Comment: I don't think it will split data from same partitions to different ones, although I'm not sure and I suggest you to test the exact behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88174/discussion-between-member555-and-gprivi).